# How do I come up with an equivalent proposition with only two connectives and without using truth tables?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$(r\longleftrightarrow p)$$

How do I come up wit ha logically equivalent proposition using only the two connectives $\neg, \vee $ ? I also I need to do this without using truth tables.

Steps I took:

Creating a truth table would simplify this whole problem, but given that I can't use them I thought up of well known logical equivalences that might help solve this problem. I just can't put two and two together. Guidance in the right direction would help me a lot.

Here is what I have thus far:

$$a\longleftrightarrow b\equiv b\longleftrightarrow a\\ a\longleftrightarrow a=always\quad T\\ a\longleftrightarrow b\equiv (a\longrightarrow b)\wedge (b\longrightarrow a)\\ a\longleftrightarrow b\equiv \neg a\longleftrightarrow \neg b\\ a\longleftrightarrow \neg a=always\quad F\\$$

I know that I could find a logical equivalent by putting that proposition into something like wolfram alpha, but that won't help me figure out the logic to get to the solution.

Comment: This is $$(r\to p)\land(p\to r)$$ and one knows that, for every $a$ and $b$, $$(a\to b)=(\lnot a\lor b).$$ Can you take it from here? You will also need $$a\land b=\lnot(\lnot a \lor\lnot b).$$

Comment: @Did the last formula needs work. The second should be $p \lor \lnot r$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma *Don't be too hasty, Masterrr Henno...* :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is the fact that $A\implies B$ is equivalent to $\neg A\vee B$.  So,
$$\begin{align}
a\iff b & = (a\implies b)\wedge(b\implies a)\\
& = (\neg a\vee b)\wedge(\neg b\vee a)\\
& = \neg(\neg(\neg a\vee b)\vee\neg(\neg b\vee a))
\end{align}$$

The last equivalence comes from the fact that $A\wedge  B$ is equivalent to $\neg(\neg A\vee\neg B)$.

Comment: So, the only important logical equivalent for this problem is $(a\Longrightarrow b)\equiv (\neg a\vee b)\\ $ ?

Comment: That and $a\wedge b=\neg(\neg a\vee\neg b)$.

Comment: You just changed what you first wrote. Why?

Comment: Wanted it to look neater. I haven't changed the meaning, just the form.

Comment: I see I just noticed that you accidentally put: $A\implies B$ is equivalent to $\neg B\vee B$

I imagine that was a typo.

Comment: Yes, and I've fixed it. :)

Comment: The last equivalence that you put is the final answer?

Comment: I assume your referring to $\neg(\neg(\neg a\vee b)\vee\neg(\neg b\vee a))$.  If that's the case, then yes.

Comment: I broke it down and finally understood it.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)